# Is it possible to fetch all documents whose sub-collection contains a specific document ID?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch all documents whose sub-collection contain a specific document ID. Is there any way to do this?

For example, if the boxed document under 'enquiries' sub-collection exists, then I need the boxed document ID from 'books' collection. I couldn't figure out how to go backwards to get the parent document ID.

[image: Structure of my database]

Answer (score 3):

I make the assumption that all the sub-collections have the same name, i.e. `enquiries`. Then, you could do as follows:

1. Add a field `docId` in your `enquiries` document that contains the document ID.
2. Execute a [Collection Group query](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/1e2f17302d6a012a75f3f2d1c2c1713876d8d6a8/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/firestore.dart#L50) in order to get all the documents with the desired `docId` value (`Firestore.instance.collectionGroup("enquiries").where("docId", isEqualTo: "ykXB...").getDocuments()`).
3. Then, you loop over the results of the query and for each `DocumentReference` you call twice the `parent()` methods ([first time](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/1e2f17302d6a012a75f3f2d1c2c1713876d8d6a8/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_reference.dart#L31) you will get the `CollectionReference` and [second time](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/1e2f17302d6a012a75f3f2d1c2c1713876d8d6a8/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/collection_reference.dart#L22) you will get the `DocumentReference` of the parent document).
4. You just have to use the [id](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/1e2f17302d6a012a75f3f2d1c2c1713876d8d6a8/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/collection_reference.dart#L22) property and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("books").where("author", isEqualTo: "Arumugam").getDocuments().then((value) {
  value.documents.forEach((result) {
   var id = result.documentID;
   Firestore.instance.collection("books").document(id).collection("enquiries").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data);
    });
```

First you need to retrieve the id under the `books` collection, to be able to do that you have to do a query for example `where("author", isEqualTo: "Arumugam")`. After retrieving the `id` you can then do a query to retrieve the documents inside the collection `enquiries`

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if the boxed document under 'enquiries' sub-collection exists, then I need the boxed document ID from 'books' collection.

There is no way you can do that in a single go.

> I couldn't figure out how to go backwards to get the parent document ID.

There is no going back in Firestore as you probably were thinking. In Firebase Realtime Database we have a method named `getParent()`, which does exactly what you want but in Firestore we don't.

Queries in Firestore are shallow, meaning that it only get items from the collection that the query is run against. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one go. A single query may only use the properties of documents in a single collection. So the solution to solving your problem is to perform two `get()` calls. The first one would be to check that document for existence in the `enquiries` subcollection, and if it exists, simply create another `get()` call to get the document from the `books` collection.

Comment: Hey yesharish! Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 1):

Renaud Tarnec's answer is great for fetching the IDs of the relevant books.

If you need to fetch more than the ID, there is a trick you could use in some scenarios. I imagine your goal is to show some sort of an index of all books associated with a particular enquiry ID. If the data you'd like to show in that index is not too long (can be serialized in less than 1500 bytes) and if it is not changing frequently, you could try to use the document ID as the placeholder for that data.

For example, let's say you wanted to display a list of book titles and authors  corresponding to some `enquiryId`. You could create the book ID in the collection with something like so:

```js
// Assuming admin SDK

const bookId = nanoid();
const author = 'Brandon Sanderson';
const title = 'Mistborn: The Final Empire';

// If title + author are not unique, you could add the bookId to the array
const uniquePayloadKey = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify([author, title])).toString('base64url');

booksColRef.doc(uniquePayloadKey).set({ bookId })
booksColRef.doc(uniquePayloadKey).collection('enquiries').doc(enquiryId).set({ enquiryId })
```

Then, after running the collection group query per Renaud Tarnec's answer, you could extract that serialized information with a regexp on the path, and deserialize. E.g.:

```js
// Assuming Web 9 SDK

const books = query(collectionGroup(db, 'enquiries'), where('enquiryId', '==', enquiryId));

return getDocs(books).then(snapshot => {
  const data = []
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const payload = doc.ref.path.match(/books\/(.*)\/enquiries/)[1];
    const [author, title] = JSON.parse(atob(details));
    data.push({ author, title })
  });
  return data;
});
```

The "store payload in ID" trick can be used only to present some basic information for your child-driven search results. If your book document has a lot of information you'd like to display once the user clicks on one of the books returned by the enquiry, you may want to store this in separate documents whose IDs are the real `bookId`s. The `bookId` field added under the unique payload key allows such lookups when necessary.

You can reuse the same data structure for returning book results from different starting points, not just enquiries, without duplicating this structure. If you stored many authors per book, for example, you could add an authors sub-collection to search by. As long as the information you want to display in the resulting index page is the same and can be serialized within the 1500-byte limit, you should be good.

The (quite substantial) downside of this approach is that [it is not possible to rename document IDs in Firestore](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/c/CMDZrinM8q0/m/TGDOUnj2BAAJ). If some of the details in the payload change (e.g. an admin fixes a book titles), you will need to create all the sub-collections under it and delete the old data. This can be quite costly - at least 1 read, 1 write, and 1 delete for every document in every sub-collection. So keep in mind it may not be pragmatic for fast changing data.

The 1500-byte limit for key names is documented in [Usage and Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

If you are concerned about potential hotspots this can generate per [Best Practices for Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices), I imagine that adding the `bookId` as a prefix to the `uniquePayloadKey` (with a delimiter that allows you to throw it away) would do the trick - but I am not certain.